# Module from 1.8 not working in 1.8.1 The type or namespace name 'Orchard' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I created my module in Orchard 1.8 and when installing it in orchard 1.8.1 I get an error:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Orchard' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 89:                 <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
Line 90:                 <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
Line 91:                 <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html"/>
Line 92:             </namespaces>
Line 93:         </pages>
```

The error is coused by an ajax call. I have checked that I am using the same jquery that in the previous version. Any ideas why this would happpen?

Comment: Try compiling your module in Visual Studio and see what errors come forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. It was in web.config since I am running webapi in the same application pool I had to add   So that webapi doesent inherit from Orchard. So the problem was not in the version at all.

Comment: You had to add what to get it to work? Could you be more specific in your answer. I know it would help others - because I am in the others category looking for what I need to do with a particular module that seems to find the references when I dbl click the errors in VS - they go away then I build No Errors - except output window says failed and lists errors in the logging.

Comment: It has been so long ago I don't remember what I did.. But from what I can piece together I had a webapi running in the same application pool as a subapplication and its web.config was set to inherit from orchard and it inherited some wrong files so I had to change that so it didn't inherit..

Comment: thanks. I had done some more research and in my situation I had found similar the referenced assembly in a module mismatched the Orchard assembly installed.